# Run single page HTML and JavaScript page offline in iPad 1 safari

Tags: html, ios, ipad, safari, offline

I am coaching my son's flag football team this winter and I'd like to make a little one pager app with jquery which will display and animate for the team some plays during huddles. I have been researching this quite a bit and it seems there is no way for safari to load local files. Some have suggested using goodreader, the app, but according to their manual they use a simplified browser rather than safari.

Not sure what else to try. The iPad is wifi only using ios5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using HTML5 built in APPCACHE: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/

We went undefeated BTW :)

Answer (score 3):

Safari is not capable of loading local files.

You have a few different options. You can:

1. Upload the file to Dropbox, and use it's offline mode to view it.
2. Use a native / hybrid container (like Appcelerator, PhoneGap, etc)
   to bundle your HTML/Javascript into a "native" app.

Answer (score 0):

No Safari can not load local files. You can't run local applications from there. What you can do is develop an actual app for your iphone using dreamweaver/jQuery. You could make pre-recorded videos and play them on your iPad as well. Goodreader, from what I can tell, is for reading local PDFs, which has nothing to do with apps... (but I don't really know)

This page should give you a general idea of using JQuery (mobile) to develop and actual app:
http://jquerymobile.com/

Edit: I just thought of a simpler approach that should work. Open a drop-box account at dropbox.com and put the website/Jquery in the public folder. Get the URL for the public folder and use that. Open the website on your iPad and then don't close the window. Even when the network connections stops it should still work.